# Accessing Kubernetes service on port 80

Tags: python, http, networking, flask, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes service (a Python Flask application) exposed publicly on port 30000 (All Kubernetes NodePorts have to be in the range 30000-32767 from what I understand) using the LoadBalancer type. I need for my public-facing service to be accessible on the standard HTTP port 80. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Right now I see all answersa are related to creating a service directly  to pod port. I am thinking OP probably want to ask how we can forward request from port 80 or 443 to Node Port such as 30000. I have tried to use iptables to add reroute rule but it failed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use cloud provider's LB, assuming your app expose on port 8080 and you want to publicly expose it on port 80, here is how the configuration should look:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask_app
  labels:
    run: flask_app
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    run: flask_app
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask_app
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: flask_app
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - name: flask_app
        image: repo/flask_app:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Another option is to use a Ingress Controller, for example Nginx.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: The working example link is broken. Please fix it if the target exists in another location, or remove it if the target no longer exists.

Comment: Do you mean: “If you DON’T want to use cloud provider’s LB... “

Answer (score 17):

If you don't use any cloudproviders, you can just set `externalIPs` option in service and make this IP up on node, and kube-proxy will route traffic from this IP to your pod for you.

```
{
    "kind": "Service",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "my-service"
    },
    "spec": {
        "selector": {
            "app": "MyApp"
        },
        "ports": [
            {
                "name": "http",
                "protocol": "TCP",
                "port": 80,
                "targetPort": 9376
            }
        ],
        "externalIPs" : [
            "80.11.12.10"
        ]
    }
}
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips

Comment: This is extremely useful for exposing internal Load Balancers to the public, in case you don't want to use the Load Balancer of your cloud provider.

Comment: For some reason that I dont have time to investigate at the moment, this solution did not work for me. However, I've came up with a working setup with the `hostNetwork` spec field. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519980/assign-external-ip-to-a-kubernetes-service/55736169#55736169  for further details

Comment: Can we also add a Route here to connect a domain?