# Assign External IP to a Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, networking

The whole point of my setup is to achieve (if possible) the following:

- I have multiple k8s nodes
- When I contact an IP address (from my company's network), it should be routed to one of my container/pod/service/whatever.
- I should be able to easily setup that IP (like in my service .yml definition)

I'm running a small Kubernetes cluster (built with kubeadm) in order to evaluate if I can move my Docker (old)Swarm setup to k8s. The feature I absolutely need is the ability to assign IP to containers, like I do with MacVlan.

In my current docker setup, I'm using MacVlan to assign IP addresses from my company's network to some containers so I can reach directly (without reverse-proxy) like if it's any physical server. I'm trying to achieve something similar with k8s.

I found out that:

- I have to use *Service*
- I can't use the *LoadBalancer* type, as it's only for compatible cloud providers (like GCE or AWS).
- I should use [*ExternalIPs*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips)
- *Ingress Resources* are some kind of reverse proxy ?

My yaml file is :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
      name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: k8s-slave-3
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  externalIPs: 
    - A.B.C.D
```

I was hopping that my service would get the IP A.B.C.D (which is one of my company's network). My deployment is working as I can reach my nginx container from inside the k8s cluster using it's *ClusterIP*.

What am I missing ? Or at least, where can I find informations on my network traffic in order to see if packets are coming?

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME            CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes      10.96.0.1      <none>            443/TCP   6d
nginx-service   10.102.64.83   A.B.C.D           80/TCP    23h
```

Comment: Are you sure that  the external IP mentioned routes to the k8s cluster nodes ? Also, what do you see when you run kubectl get service ?

Comment: Can you try without specifying `type: ClusterIP`

Comment: I added `kubectl get svc` output as EDIT. Removing `type: ClusterIP` does not change anything as it's the default value. How can I check if the traffic comes to my cluster ? In `kube-proxy` ?

Comment: You service has been assigned the external IP. Why don't you hit the external IP on port 80 ?

Comment: I do and it's not working. That's the point. My container is reachable from inside my cluster but not from outside.

Comment: a Service with ExternalIP only means, that incoming traffic, which is for A.B.C.D, will be routed to the service endpoint. You still need to make sure that traffic to A.B.C.D is routed to one of the k8s nodes, so that kube-proxy can handle it. Usually that means that A.B.C.D is one of the k8s nodes IP addresses. Is that the case in your setup?

Comment: I thought k8s will handle IP assignement for me. So I will try to assign A.B.C.D to one on my node. But that means (a) I have to manually assign that IP to my node and (b) the traffic has to come one that node ?

Comment: @JérômePin Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @MaxEhrlich No, not really. I changed my policy : only http services can be user-facing. There is no need for external IP, I put a reverse-proxy in front of it (and/or I use k8s's Ingress ressources).

Comment: @JérômePin I found today that if I expose the services with no load balancer running and static ips (this is a bare metal install), then make macvtap devices with the assigned external IP on the master (which can be accessed from outside cluster), it works as expected. I will probably make a python script that creates these macvtap devices automatically when kubernetes deploys a new service. I doubt this is a good idea for production.

Comment: @MaxEhrlich Great trick ! But I doubt too :)

Comment: From https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/: "externalIPs are not managed by Kubernetes and are the responsibility of the cluster administrator." - The question is now if there are "LoadBalancer controllers" similar to network or ingress controllers which I can install?

Comment: @DanielAlder, by "LoadBalancer controllers", if you talk about a LoadBalancer service, it's only available for some cloud providers. For bare-metal cluster, beside ingress, you can check out [metallb](https://github.com/google/metallb).

Answer (score 49):

First of all run this command:

```
kubectl get -n namespace services
```

Above command will return output like this:

```
 NAME            TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
backend   NodePort   10.100.44.154         <none>          9400:3003/TCP   13h   
frontend        NodePort   10.107.53.39     <none>        3000:30017/TCP   13h
```

It is clear from the above output that External IPs are not assigned to the services yet. To assign External IPs to *backend* service run the following command.

```
 kubectl patch svc backend -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["192.168.0.194"]}}'
```

and to assign external IP to *frontend* service run this command.

```
 kubectl patch svc frontend -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["192.168.0.194"]}}'
```

Now get namespace service to check either external IPs assignment:

```
kubectl get -n namespace services
```

We get an output like this:

```
NAME     TYPE     CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)             AGE
backend  NodePort 10.100.44.154  192.168.0.194  9400:3003/TCP       13h
frontend NodePort 10.107.53.39   192.168.0.194  3000:30017/TCP      13h
```

Cheers!!! Kubernetes External IPs are now assigned .

Comment: how can replace an already existing Ip (assigned by the LoadBalancer MetalLB)? ix-putty         
In `putty                   LoadBalancer   172.17.25.2      10.10.8.211,10.10.12.211   10266/TCP` the `10.10.8.211` always stays even if `kubectl patch svc -n ix-putty putty-vnc -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":[]}}` is done.

Answer (score 26):

If this is just for testing, then try

```
kubectl port-forward service/nginx-service 80:80
```

Then you can

```
curl http://localhost:80
```

Comment: I used `kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 pod/<my pod> 6666:6666` to expose port 6666 on pod to outside world.

`curl http://<PUBLIC IP>:6666` works fine but if I try to access the same link in browser then I get `this site can't be reached` error. Any idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: @rakesh 

The easiest way to test your 'port-forward' using a public address, use something like ngrok (https://ngrok.com/)


Start your proxy
   `kubectl port-forward po/myapp 8080:3000`

Start ngrok proxy
   `ngrok http 8080`


ngrok will provide 2 public URLS (http/https) routing request to your machine's port 8080

Answer (score 7):

You can just Patch an External IP

CMD: `$ kubectl patch svc svc_name -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["your_external_ip"]}}'`

Eg:- `$ kubectl patch svc kubernetes -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["10.2.8.19"]}}'`

Answer (score 5):

A solution that could work (and not only for testing, **though it has its shortcomings**) is to set your Pod to map the host network with the `hostNetwork` spec field set to `true`.

It means that you won't need a service to expose your Pod, as it will always be accessible on your host via a single port (the `containerPort` you specified in the manifest). No need to keep a DNS mapping record in that case.

This also means that you can only run a single instance of this Pod on a given node (talking about shortcomings...). As such, it makes it a good candidate for a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) object.

If your Pod still needs to access/resolve internal Kubernetes hostnames, you need to set the `dnsPolicy` spec field set to `ClusterFirstWithNoHostNet`. This setting will enable your pod to access the K8S DNS service.

Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-reverse-proxy
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      tolerations:  # allow a Pod instance to run on Master - optional
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
```

EDIT: I was put on this track thanks to the the [ingress-nginx documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/deploy/baremetal.md)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add "type: NodePort" in your yaml file for the service and then you'll have a port to access it via the web browser or from the outside. For my case, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the namespace flag either before or after the service name, because Namespace-based scoping is applicable for deployments and services and this points out to the service that is tagged to a specific namespace.

```
kubectl patch svc service-name -n namespace -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["IP"]}}'
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if that helps in your particular case but what I did (and I'm on a Bare Metal cluster) was to use the `LoadBalancer` and set the `loadBalancerIP` as well as the `externalIPs` to my server IP as you did it.

After that the correct external IP showed up for the load balancer.

Comment: This is what I need, can you please expand the answer with examples?

Answer (score -2):

Just include additional option.

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=LoadBalancer --name=my-service --external-ip=1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Well, it's a pretty old issue I had. But at that time I wasn't able to use the LoadBalancer type as it was a bare-metal cluster. Plus, using `--external-ip=1.1.1.1` in this example is not the best idea as this IP address is now Cloudflare's public DNS.