# Unable to see my react application after deploying into Kubernetes

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr

I've followed this reference to deploy my simple react application into Kubernetes.

**https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/aws-deploying-react-app-with-nodejs-backend-on-eks-e5663cb5017f**

[image]

But after deploying, I can't see my application in the browser.

So I tried to set external ip address using this command line

```
kubectl patch svc XXX -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["10.2.8.19"]}}'
```

Reference is here
[Assign External IP to a Kubernetes Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519980/assign-external-ip-to-a-kubernetes-service)

[image]

But I can't see my application deployed in the browser.
http://10.2.8.192:3000

Here is my deployment.yml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: test-app
  name: test-app
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: test-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: XXX.dkr.ecr.XXX.amazonaws.com/XXX/XXX:v1
        name: test-app
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources: {}
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3000
status: {}

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-app
  labels:
    run: test-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: test-app
  type: NodePort
```

Please give me any advice. Thank you...

Comment: Hey Max! Do you have network access to the nodes ? can you ping them ?

Comment: I need to ping with public ip address in EC2 instance?

Comment: Or you mean pinging with nodeport in Kubernetes?

Comment: What Kubernetes are you using?  If it's EKS, changing the service to `type: LoadBalancer` will cause it to create an AWS load balancer, and you can use that to access the service.  If it's `type: NodePort` then you'd access it using any of the nodes' IP addresses or DNS names, and the second 31300 port number from the `kubectl get service` listing.

Comment: I am using NodePort now. and what is nodes's IP addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing 2 ways to expose service outside. You want to use `NodePort` but you are setting `ExternalIP`.

#### Issue root cause

In your setup, you are using `NodePort` so you need to use `ExternalIP` of the node with `NodePort` which is `31300` (more details below).

Setting `ExternalIP` in `NodePort` service in this setup is pointless (also `10.2.8.19` is `InternalIP` which allows you to connect only in cluster).

In your example, you are trying to reach application using your `application port` number, but you should use service `nodePort` number, which is `31300`.

**Note**

A Service can map any incoming port to a targetPort. By default and for convenience, the targetPort is set to the same value as the port field.

#### Exposing application

Generally, you have 3 main ways to expose your application:

- [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)

I don't have access to `medium` article, but I guess in this tutorial `NodePort` was used.

In this configuration, you have to use `serviceType: NodePort`. To connect using `nodeport`, you have to use `ExternalHostIP:NodePort`. As you are using cloud environment, your VM should already have `ExternalIP`.

`ExternalHostIP` is IP address of node, where application endpoint pod was deployed. To get `ExternalIP` of `Node` you can use command.
`$ kubectl get node -o wide`

To get information on what node, specific pod was deployed you can execute command
`$ kubectl get po  -o wide

`NodePort` number is assigned from range `30000-32767`.

**IMPORTANT**
Please remember to configure fiewall to allow traffic on this specific port, or if it's just for testing you can allow whole range `30000-32767`.

**Example**
Let's say your application pod was deployed on `Node` with `ExternalIP: 35.228.76.198` and your `service NodePort` is 31300.

If you configured firewall rules correctly and right `containerPort` (your application must listen on this port) was set, when you will use `35.228.76.198:31300` in the browser, you should reach your application.

- [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer)

In this option, service is `LoadBalancer` type, which means that cloud is creating `LB` with `ExternalIP`. You just need to enter this IP in your browser to reach your application. However, please remember that `LoadBalancer` is extra paid.

- [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

In this option you have to use some kind of `Ingress Controller`. Most common is [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/). In this option, depends of your needs you can create Ingress as `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` option.

**Usefull links**

- [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)
- [Exposing application in AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-kubernetes-services-cluster/)
- [Nginx Ingress on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/)

Please let me know if you was able to reach your application or you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose your application with a `NodePort` you can have a look [How do I expose the Kubernetes services running on my Amazon EKS cluster?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-kubernetes-services-cluster/):

- It looks like your `Deployment` is missing a `targetPort`.
- `kubectl get nodes` should return the `NodeIP`.
- `NodeIP:NodePort` should be reachable if you enable the security group of the nodes to allow incoming traffic through port `31300`.

Comment: How can I get NodeIP? 
"kubectl get nodes" returns each node's internal ip address. Should I use public address in EC2 instance?