# Is it possible to connect pgsql running in Kubernetes cluster using clients like Dbeaver or SQLDeveloper outside of cluster?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, dbeaver

i am trying to connect dbeaver from outside the cluster but it seems i can't establish the connection with the pgsql, have tried port forwarding in kubernetes but still it didn't solved the problem, just point which all things i should check?

Edit1: kubernetes in running in remote ubuntu box and am dbeaver is in my machine which is having a different ip address? kubernetes is not running on my machine.

Comment: Yes. We can use, for example, port forwards to the local machine. If it does not work, it sounds like a misconfiguration.

Comment: but kubernetes is not running in my machine its a different linux box, any reference link would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If the remote ubuntu box can expose other ports (other than SSH) you could go with a NodePort service (which is a good idea for development environments but NOT really for production). Even if the ubuntu box can expose only SSH, you can always create a NodePort service to expose your postgresql and then conect Dbeaver with an SSH tunnel.

Comment: Thanks @AndD i haven't tried NodePort will try it.

Comment: Hi @marco525, any progress?

Comment: Hi @Mikolaj, yes it worked, i'll write the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Thanks @Turing85 and @AndD.

My postgres pod is running in Kubernetes cluster eg.(IP:192.168.0.1).

1. Logged into the cluster and fired this command:

   kubectl get services
2. After getting services fired below command to map external ip to my service, i have exposed it to same ip where cluster is running.

   kubectl patch svc backend -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["192.168.0.1"]}}'

detailed example: [Assign External IP to a Kubernetes Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519980/assign-external-ip-to-a-kubernetes-service)

3. After that just provided connection settings(ip,dbusername,dbname,passowrd,port) in dbeaver and it worked.